# Pandas Compare between Two DataFrames, flag what matches

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have to dataframes- `df` and `df1`

`df` is below

```
Facility    Category ID   Part  Text
Centennial  History 11111   A   Drain
Centennial  History 11111   B   Read
Centennial  History 11111   C   EKG
Centennial  History 11111   D   Assistant 
Centennial  History 11111   E   Primary
```

`df1` is below (Just included a small sample for the question, it is actually 50,000 rows)

```
Facility    Category  ID      Part   Text
Centennial  History  11111    D      Assistant
```

Basically I want to compare rows between dataframes and if the row matches between two dataframes then create a another column in the first dataframe `df` with the column header as `['MatchingFlag']`

My end result dataframe, I would like to look like this below as I'm just as concerned about the ones that do not match.

```
Facility    Category  ID    Part    Text      MatchingFlag
Centennial  History  11111  A     Drain         No
Centennial  History  11111  B     Read          No
Centennial  History  11111  C     EKG           No
Centennial  History  11111  D     Assistant     Yes
Centennial  History  11111  E     Primary       No
```

Any help on how to do this? I've tried merging `df = pd.merge(df1, df, how='left', on=['Facility', 'Category', 'ID', 'Part', 'Text'])` the two dataframes, and then create a flag based on blank or NaN values, but that doesn't do what I was hoping.

Comment: Sorry is your second df literally just a single row?

Comment: no it is more, I just included a small sample size for the question

Comment: I edited that part to show that it's a small sample size

Comment: that sounds like you're trying to test between the 2 dfs, so if a row is in the other df but in the first df then no flag correct? you could just do `df.merge(df1)` this will return all matching rows and then just set the flag to `True` for those

Comment: thanks for the comments and I probably should have clarified better (i'll edit for more clarity) I'm just as concerned about the ones that do not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might make sense to set an index on the columns you want to match on, and use that index to sort out which rows match

```
columns = ['Facility', 'Category', 'ID', 'Part', 'Text']

# It's always a good idea to sort after creating a MultiIndex like this
df = df.set_index(columns).sortlevel()
df1 = df1.set_index(columns).sortlevel()

# You don't have to use Yes here, anything will do
# The boolean True might be more appropriate
df['MatchingFlag'] = "Yes"
df1['MatchingFlag'] = "Yes"

# Add them together, matching rows will have the value "YesYes"
# Non-matches will be nan
result = df + df1

# If you'd rather not have NaN's 
result.loc[:,'MatchingFlag'] = result.loc[:,'MatchingFlag'].replace('YesYes','Yes')
result.loc[:,'MatchingFlag'] = result['MatchingFlag'].fillna('No')
```

Comment: yeah see I tried something similar and using 'inner' only returns the 1matching row, using 'left' in your example returns all 5 rows with all of them having a 'Yes' for ['MatchingFlag']             
         `Facility         Category   ID       Part Text    MatchingFlag
0 Centennial History 11111 A Drain Yes
1 Centennial History 11111 B Read Yes
2 Centennial History 11111 C EKG Yes
3 Centennial History 11111 D Assistant Yes
4 Centennial History 11111 E Primary Yes`

Comment: Oh yeah, I hadn't had enough coffee yet. Should have been an outer merge to return all rows, my bad

Comment: I really appreciate you helping, so still in your example, using outer, it still returns 5 rows, with every row having "Yes" under ['MatchingFlag']. This is #Tricky

Comment: Ah of course, that technique only works when you set the flag before hand on the dataframe that is strictly smaller than the other, which may not always be the case. I'll update to something that will work

Comment: awesome dude, works perfect. Might I add you include this at the end in case someone views this. so that it puts it back looking like the original df. `result.reset_index()`