# compare two dataframes and create a boolean table or flag

Tags: pandas, numpy, openpyxl, python-2.6

Df and Df1

df  is mock representative

```
Country      Category Brand
South Africa Health   Proctor
America      Shoe     Nike
America      Clothing Forever21  
UK           Car      Rover
```

df1

```
Country      Category Brand
South Africa Health   Proctor
America      Shoe     Nike
America      Clothing Forever21  
UK           £!"4     11111
```

I want to compare the two and create and return a new table showing they match i.e.

**Solution 1: Df3 Match Check Boolean Output**

```
Country Category Brand
True    True     True 
True    True     True 
True    True     True 
True    False    False
```

**Desired Solution 2: Df3 output with openpyxl**

[Desired openxyl output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYL2w.png)

preferably i'd like use openpyxl to compare two dataframe tables and return the conditional format excel file.

**Kit i'm using (if it helps):**

**python 2.6** 
**pandas 0.16**
**numpy 1.9.2**
**openpyxl 2.4.8**

Comment: I'm wondering why `df_res = df == df1` didn't work.

Comment: have you tried df_res = df.as_matrix == df1.as_matrix. These you numpy arrays which will do an element wise comparison.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You really need to move off Python 2.6

Comment: @charlie clark I'm not able to move out of 2.6. due to restrictions.

Comment: i've tried to use  [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024537/pandas-compare-between-two-dataframes-flag-what-matches)  but it didn't meet my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Attempt at Second Solution**

```
red_color = 'ffc7ce'
diff_val =  np.where((df!= df1).any(1) == True)
df_result = pd.DataFrame(diff_val.columns)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df_result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Applying a conditional format to the cell range.
for item in diff_result:
    df_result.append(df.iloc[item], df1.iloc[item])
    worksheet.conditional_format(df1, {'type': 'unique', 'format':red_color})
# # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```